# How do I select all <th> elements of class "sortasc" within a table with a specific id?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="foo">
  <th class="sortasc">Header</th>
</table>

<table id="bar">
  <th class="sortasc">Header</th>
</table>
```

I know that I can do the following to get all of the **th** elements that have class="sortasc"

```
$$('th.sortasc').each()
```

However that gives me the **th** elements from both table *foo* and table *bar*.

How can I tell it to give me just the th elements from table *foo*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

table#foo th.sortasc

Comment: Crud.  I figured it was easy but I didn't think it was that easy.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you'd do it with straight-up JS:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
var headers = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
var headersIWant = [];
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  if ((' ' + headers[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' sortasc ') >= 0) {
    headersIWant.push(headers[i]);
  }
}
return headersIWant;
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector would be something like '#foo th.sortasc'. In jQuery that would be $('#foo th.sortasc').

Answer (score 0):

With a nested table, like:

```
<table id="foo">
  <th class="sortasc">Header</th>
  <tr><td>
    <table id="nestedFoo">
      <th class="sortasc">Nested Header</th>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

$('table#foo th.sortasc') will give you *all* the th's because you're using a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors). If you only want foo's th's, then you should use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) - $('table#foo > th.sortasc').

Note that the child selector is [not supported](http://kimblim.dk/csstest/#ex1) in CSS for IE6, though JQuery will still correctly do it from JavaScript.

Comment: Also note that if your th elements are within a thead or tbody or tfoot, this will fail. You'll want $$('table#foo > th.sortasc, table#foo > thead th.sortasc, table#foo > tbody th.sortasc, table#foo > tfoot th.sortasc'), which is a bit unweildy...